# Comparing as2 to as1

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, eval

For my recent project I need to work with as1.

The problem is that I have a little bit forgotten as1, I think my last coding in as1 was nearly 8 years ago.

My first question is, is there any web site to refererence as1 syntax or an as2 to as1 guide?
Second one is about eval(). Is there is any difference between as2 eval to as1 eval.

Comment: no real difference between the two, no. have fun without functions and arrays... yikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great place to start is the As1 reference:

- http://www.ivy.fr/asapi/

Comment: Link is dead - 404